# Setting Up OAuth App - Process Gets Stuck

Tags: support

After I had some initial issues from errors on the stack exchange side which were resolved, the authorization appears to work but every time I try to start the process I get brought to this page below and that is it, it never actually authorizes anything. Has anybody run into this?

[image]

Comment: What's the URL shown in the address bar at that moment?

Comment: Hi again! :) The address is https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success?scope=read_inbox+no_expiry+write_access+private_info&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fauth.cloudelements.io%2Foauth&state=stackoverflow&client_id=1xxx6

Comment: Hi! I don't understand how you get redirected there - it looks very much like the URL you should direct the user to, which is https://stackoverflow.com/oauth?scope=read_inbox+no_expiry+write_access+private_info&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fauth.cloudelements.io%2Foauth&state=stackoverflow&client_id=1xxx6 That should redirect to auth.cloudelements.io, not to stackexchange.com

Comment: Yeah, really stumped. I also have Cloud Elements looking into it and they haven't been able to figure it out either. For whats its worth if I make the call directly in postman or insomnia I get the same result